# Will there is always one record exist for share?

Tags: soql, apex-managed-sharing

i fetch the share record using below soql

```
List<sObject>shareList = new List<sObject>();
For( Test1__c primaryRecord  : [select id , (select id from shares)  from Test1__c])
```

Then i am using below to get share record inside the for loop,

```
 shareList.add(primaryRecord.getSObjects('Shares'));
```

will it give null error ? Do i need a checkpoint here. ?

```
if(primaryRecord.getSObjects('Shares') <> NULL)
 {
     sharelist.add(primaryRecord.getSObjects('Shares'));
}
```

I tested to create on test record and checked for share record. I found there is one is created for owner.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, If you have access to a record, it should have atleast one `Share` record. Having a null check is always better.

Comment: For custom spec sharing there could be multiple for a given user

Answer (score 0):

```
List<sObject> shareList = new List<sObject>();
For( Test1__c primaryRecord  : [select id , (select id from shares)  from Test1__c])
{
  shareList.addAll((new List<Sobject>(primaryRecord.getSObjects('shares'))));    
}
```

This saved me from null and avoid to retrive the getSObjects twice.